# Mutiple where condition in sql query

Tags: php, mysql

My db structure is as follows:

```
tender_id | slab_range | slab_checked | item_name
________________________________________________
1           2-3            Yes           Item1
1           2-7            No            Item2
1           2-9            Yes           Item 3
2                          No            Item4
2                          NULL          Item5
```

I need some multiple where condition to be checked in the query

First Condition is Show records only if slab_range value is there (Not Null), if slab_range value is there then it should show only records with Slab_checked=Yes

Next condition is if slab_range = NULL Then its should show all records with slab_checked = No or Null

This is the basic query which i need to change as per the above:

```
select tender_id, slab_range, slab_checked,item_name 
from quotation_items 
where tender_id='$tender_id' 
and (slab_range=!NULL or slab_checked='Yes' or slab_checked='') 
or  (slab_checked='No' or slab_checked='') 
order by item_name
```

Expected Result is

Expected Result

```
tender_id | slab_range | slab_checked | item_name
________________________________________________
1           2-3            Yes           Item1
1           2-9            Yes           Item 3
2                          No            Item4
2                          NULL          Item5
```

Comment: what is the expected result?

Comment: The results are dynamic. I need a query with 2 where conditions. First Condition is Show records only if slab_range value is there (Not Null), if slab_range value is there then it should show only records with Slab_checked=Yes. Next condition is if slab_range = NULL Then its should show all records with slab_checked = No or Null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
select tender_id, slab_range, slab_checked,item_name 
from quotation_items 
where tender_id='$tender_id' 
and (
    (slab_range is not NULL and (slab_checked='Yes')) 
       or  
    (slab_range is NULL and (slab_checked='No' or slab_checked is NULL))
)
order by item_name
```

You might need to replace `is NULL` and `is NOT NULL` with `<> ''` and `= ''`, depending on whether `slab_range` actually contains NULLs or empty strings (based on your desired output it seems to contain empty strings)